# Is there anyway to change a (custom) scrollbar in Microsoft Edge via react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, microsoft-edge

I want to customize scroll bar in Microsoft Edge. It's easy to Chrome, but these codes doesn't work with Edge, so is there any way to do it?

I tried these functions but they're not working:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar 
::-webkit-scrollbar-button 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner 
::-webkit-resizer
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Thanks for posting sample abbreviated css. Do you have additional sample code to go with this? Are you selecting the correct component? More detail invites better answers.

Comment: As of Edge 79, ::-webkit-scrollbar is supported. Thus, the only major browser that doesn't support this is Firefox, which only supports scrollbar-color and scrollbar-width.

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar 
::-webkit-scrollbar-button 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner 
::-webkit-resizer
```

Please check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar), the above style of the scrollbar is not supported the Edge browser. So it doesn't work on Edge browser.

[image]

As a workaround, I suggest you could try to search/use some JQuery custom scrollbar plugin, for example: [SimpleBar](https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
* {
    scrollbar-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1);
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```